# Keypress event in javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx-8, keypress

[i am trying to addition of two numbers when 2nd number assigns keypress evet, number is entering automatically result display in total text field ,but i cant got my required output

```
@FXML
private TextField Number1;

@FXML
private TextField Number2;

@FXML
private TextField total;

@FXML
void Total(KeyEvent event) {
    total.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(Number2.getText())));

}
```

Total is the keypress method.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssdho.png)
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssdho.png)

Comment: To which node `Total()` listener method is bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for text changes in `Number2` using `textProperty()` rather than `keyPress` event

```
    Number2.textProperty().addListener((ov,oldValue,newVal)->{

        total.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Number1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(newVal)));

    });
```

Also make sure that you used `TextFormatter` for `Number1` and `Number2` for allowing valid inputs only